# How to create query specific projections with Vertica Database Designer?

Tags: database, vertica

How should the script be fed to Vertica's database designer when I want to create query-specific projections ?
  Can I write more then one `SELECT` statement inside the file that will be provided as input to the DB designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a text file with the queries you want to optimize for. When prompted in the DBD process, point it to that file.

When I was working on/discussing optimxation using Vertica Database Designer it seems like the recommended upper limit for queries in the file was 100.

If you want to weigh a query more heavily, put that in multiple times.

Comment: what do you mean with : "If you want to weight a query more heavily, put the it in multiple times." ?

Comment: If you have a query that is going to be executed more often, or you want it the projections to be more optimized for, you can include it multiple times to give that 'query family' more weight when it generates the optimized projections.  it doesn't create a projection per query, it does analysis on the queries and attempts to create a set of projections that will handle the queries. The more often similar queries occur will result in better optimized query for those types. I haven't done a lot with the DBD, used it as a starting point  but have hand done most of my projections.